# Can I skip episodes in Shipudden?

Tags: naruto

Currently, I'm at 52 when Team Kakashi meets Sasuke. I really want to see Naruto in sage mode which is somewhere around 150 episode. So which all episodes (fillers) can I skip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following episode ranges are filler episodes in Naruto shippuden:
57-71, 90-112, 127-128, 144-151, 170-171, 176-178, 180-196, 223-242, 257-260, 271, 279-281, 284-295, 303-320, 347-361, 376-377, 388-390, 394-413, 416-417, 419, 422-423, 427-455

Canon Episodes:
1-56, 72-89, 113-126, 129-143, 152-169, 172-175, 179, 197-222, 243-256, 261-270, 272-278, 282-283, 296-302, 321-346, 362-375, 378-387, 391-393, 414-415, 418, 420-421, 424-426

If you want to see naruto in sage mode, the episode you are looking for episode 163.